# Recursive Method to create Json object

Tags: java, json, recursion

I like to know how I might do the following:

I want to create a json format of the following:

I want to be able to create a recursive function that takes an object holding a list of other objects of the same type and in a method to recursively create the format below.

```
{
    "name": "lib",
    "contains": [{
        "name": "room",
        "contains": [{
            "name": "bookshelf",
            "contains": [{
                "name": "shelf",
                "contains": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I have this as the following method:

```
private JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

public  JSONObject setupLib(Contains contain) {

    int count = contain.getContainerList().size();

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        try {

            json.put("name", contain.getContainerList().get(i).getContainerName());

            if(contain.getContainerList().size() != 0) {
                Contains contains = (Contains) contain.getContainerList().get(i);

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

                json.put("contain",array.put(setupLib(contains)));}
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.i(Tag, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return json;
```

}
I get a stackoverflow on the array/object

Comment: You need to provide the complete code for `setupLib` or better yet a small self-contained compilable example that demonstrates the problem. What is the `json` variable in your code? What does `setupLib` return?

Comment: I added the return values, it should return a build json like the format above. Just not sure how to get the recursion to work.

Comment: Your if statement for an empty list is pointless because the for loop already does that. And if you were to use Gson library, you could very easily serialize your class object

Comment: what do you mean with serialize and how would it allow me to create the multiple objects in a recursive method? Shouldn't this just work as well somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options

1. Do it yourself recursively
2. Use a library such as [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to save you the development time and effort

Since this is a learning experience, I have shown both that return this JSON.

```
{
    "name": "lib",
    "contains": [{
        "name": "room",
        "contains": [{
            "name": "bookshelf",
            "contains": [{
                "name": "shelf",
                "contains": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Contains lib = new Contains("lib");
    Contains room = new Contains("room");
    Contains bookshelf = new Contains("bookshelf");
    Contains shelf = new Contains("shelf");

    bookshelf.add(shelf);
    room.add(bookshelf);
    lib.add(room);

    // Option 1
    System.out.println(setupLib(lib).toJSONString());

    // Option 2
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(lib));
}

private static JSONObject setupLib(Contains contain) {
    if (contain == null) return null;
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for (Contains c : contain.getContainerList()) {
        JSONObject innerContain = setupLib(c);
        if (innerContain != null) {
            array.add(innerContain);
        }
    }
    map.put("name", contain.getName());
    map.put("contains", array);

    return new JSONObject(map);
}
```

This is the model object, for reference

```
public class Contains {
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("contains")
    @Expose
    private List<Contains> contains;

    public Contains(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        contains = new ArrayList<Contains>();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void add(Contains c) {
        this.contains.add(c);
    }

    public void setContainerList(List<Contains> contains) {
        this.contains = contains;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Contains> getContainerList() {
        return this.contains;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007, Appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Yeah. And I never tested why you were receiving a stack overflow, but if the objecta contained themselves, that would happen

Comment: quick question as to how I would deserialize if I were to use GSON. --> My class Contains extends Container which has an List<Container>. The class Container just has the name in there.                                                   When I try deserialize I get an object Contains but it doesn't contain other objects Contains but container.

Comment: What is the difference between a `Contains` object and a `Container`? Why do you need `Container`?

Comment: because I need to be able to add other objects within contains in this example a book object that extends Container.

Comment: If you post a new question, I'm sure someone would be willing to answer it. It is not really something that can be answer here in the comments and an edit to my answer isn't something to do for a secondary question

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah posted the question yesterday still waiting :P, Yeah. Wanted to continue on with the project but this will hold it down till I know what do to with it @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

I think is far easier if you'd serialize both the `JSONObject` and `Contains` classes. This way you'll be able to use the Jackson library to create the JSON file for you.

You can find more information about the Jackson library on the following GitHub page: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson.